# How to delete rows in pandas based on range of values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new here. Here's my problem: I am trying to drop the rows in my data frame given a range of value.
Code:

```py
outlier_age = df3[ (df3['Age']<= 17.) & (df3['Age'] >= 75.) ].index

df4 = df3.drop(outlier_age , inplace=True)
```

and I am getting this error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4169: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> errors=errors,

I feel like it has something to do with datatypes?
I tried the `==` operator just to get to try to drop at least the rows with the given value but it didn't worked.

I tried the same method on a different column, using a string and I was able to drop the rows with the specified string.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```py
df4 = df3.drop(df3.index[(df3['Age']<= 17.) & (df3['Age'] >= 75.)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an either/or problem here. Either

```
df3.drop(outlier_age , inplace=True)
```

which edits the underlying dataframe, or

```
df4 = df3.drop(outlier_age)
```

which returns a reduced dataframe.  You could also do it in a one-liner:

```
df4 = df3[ (df3['Age']>= 17.) & (df3['Age'] <= 75.) ]
```